# How to enable SAML into .net core(3.1) application with Auth0 as IDP

Tags: .net-core, saml-2.0, identity, asp.net-core-3.1, auth0

I want to enable SAMP into '.net core 3.1' application with Auth0 as IDP. I tried to explore `Auth0.AspNetCore.Authentication` but I did not find any information around SAML configuration as it's just a wrapper around `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect`.
Can someone help here with some documentation or sample code with some well proven open source library.

Thank you!

Comment: Is Auth0 account controlled by your organization or do you want to enable SAML auth for your client organization into your app?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect is for OpenId Connect.

SAML is a completely different protocol.

I don't think Auth0 have a sample for a .Net core client-side stack?

Otherwise, look [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

To configure Auth0 as a SAML IDP, look [here](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/protocols/saml/saml-sso-integrations/configure-auth0-saml-identity-provider).